# I cant insert data to mysql from my tkinter form

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

I can connect perfectly to my db, bus somehow i manage to screw up the writing part of it.
I just cant seem to find the answer, i'd really like some insight please!

**Here is my code:**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error


db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="oliver1989",
    database="pruebas_mysql"
)


def insert_newuser():
    cursor = db.cursor()

    add_usuario = """INSERT INTO reg_us(nombre, paterno, materno, usuario, contra)"
                   "VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""% (new_nombre.get(), new_paterno.get(), new_materno.get(), new_usuario.get(), new_contraseña.get())
    #data_registro = (new_nombre.get(), new_paterno.get(), new_materno.get(), new_usuario.get(), new_contraseña.get())

    cursor.execute(add_usuario)
    db.commit()

def registro_usuario():
    screen1=Toplevel(screen)
    screen1.geometry("280x400")
    screen1.config(bg="#5EC659")
    screen.title("Registro")

    global new_nombre
    new_nombre=StringVar()
    global new_paterno
    new_paterno=StringVar()
    global new_materno
    new_materno=StringVar()
    global new_usuario
    new_usuario=StringVar()
    global new_contraseña
    new_contraseña=StringVar()
    global con_contraseña
    con_contraseña=StringVar()

    Label(screen1, text="Por favor llena este formulario", font=("consolas", 10), bg="#5EC659", fg="white").pack()
    Label(screen1, text="", bg="#5EC659").pack()
    Label(screen1, text="Nombre / s", font=("consolas", 10), bg="#5EC659", fg="white").pack()
    Entry(screen1, textvariable=new_nombre).pack()
    Label(screen1, text="Apellido paterno", font=("consolas", 10), bg="#5EC659", fg="white").pack()
    Entry(screen1, textvariable=new_paterno).pack()
    Label(screen1, text="Apellido Materno", font=("consolas", 10), bg="#5EC659", fg="white").pack()
    Entry(screen1, textvariable=new_materno).pack()
    Label(screen1, text="Usuario", font=("consolas", 10), bg="#5EC659", fg="white").pack()
    Entry(screen1, textvariable=new_usuario).pack()
    Label(screen1, text="Contraseña", font=("consolas", 10), bg="#5EC659", fg="white").pack()
    Entry(screen1, textvariable=new_contraseña).pack()
    Label(screen1, text="Confirma la contraseña", font=("consolas", 10), bg="#5EC659", fg="white").pack()
    Entry(screen1, textvariable=con_contraseña).pack()
    Label(screen1, text="", bg="#5EC659").pack()
    Button(screen1, text=" Registrar", height="1", width="10", font=("consolas", 11), command=insert_newuser).pack()



def check_udb():
    print("hola")


def main_screen():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()
    screen.geometry("280x300")
    screen.config(bg="#5EC659")
    screen.title("Planeaciones 1.0")

    global usuario
    global contraseña
    usuario = StringVar()
    contraseña =StringVar()

    Label(text="Bienvenido", font=("consolas", 15), bg="#5EC659", fg="white").pack()
    Label(text="", bg="#5EC659").pack()
    Label(text="Usuario", bg="#5EC659", fg="white", font=("consolas", 13)).pack()
    Entry(screen, textvariable = usuario).pack()
    Label(text="Contraseña", bg="#5EC659", fg="white", font=("consolas", 13)).pack()
    Entry(screen, textvariable = contraseña).pack()
    Label(text="", bg="#5EC659").pack()
    Button(text="Ingresar", height="1", width="8", font=("consolas", 10), fg="#1E1E1E", command=check_udb).pack()
    Label(text="¿No cuentas con usuario?", bg="#5EC659", fg="white").pack()
    Label(text="¡Facil!, registra tu nuevo usuario.", bg="#5EC659", fg="white").pack()
    Button(text="Registrarse", height="1", width="11", font=("consolas", 10), fg="#1E1E1E", command=registro_usuario).pack()

    screen.mainloop()


main_screen()
```

**This is the error i get in console:**

> "C:\Users\ICATVER 03\PycharmProjects\pruebas
>   mysqldb\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/ICATVER
>   03/PycharmProjects/pruebas mysqldb/index.py" Exception in Tkinter
>   callback Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\ICATVER
>   03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py",
>   line 1705, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "C:/Users/ICATVER 03/PycharmProjects/pruebas mysqldb/index.py", line 22, in
>   insert_newuser
>       cursor.execute(add_usuario)   File "C:\Users\ICATVER 03\PycharmProjects\pruebas
>   mysqldb\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 551,
>   in execute
>       self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))   File "C:\Users\ICATVER 03\PycharmProjects\pruebas
>   mysqldb\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line
>   490, in cmd_query
>       result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))   File "C:\Users\ICATVER 03\PycharmProjects\pruebas
>   mysqldb\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line
>   395, in _handle_result
>       raise errors.get_exception(packet) mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"
>                      "VALUES(asdf, asdf, asdf, asdf, asdf)' at line 1

Comment: The error is saying that you have a SQL syntax error

Comment: I know, but i don't know where i messed up, I've reviewed it several times and I can't find it... maybe i'm just frustrated, been at it for two days... i'm sure its something obvious but my brain cant find it